# How to show big data chart with good performace?

Tags: javascript, charts, nvd3.js

I have a chart with points of every 5 sec. Ex.: 00:00:00; 00:00:05; 00:00:10 ... 23:59:55.

I mean, i have [30 (per minute) * 60 (per hour) * 24 (per day)] = 43,200 points in my chart. So, this is too much point to render and i dont know what is the best method to show this big data with a good performace.

I already have a chart with this 43,200 points and the system goes too slow, even when already loaded.

Im using NVD3 chart. [You can check it here](http://nvd3.org/examples/lineWithFocus.html)

Comment: Too much element is the reason lead to bad performance. You can try combine canvas with d3js. http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/db24422abdb20150a9dd

Comment: Check this, maybe it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665744/fastest-javascript-charting-library-for-really-huge-data also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971519/reduce-the-size-of-a-large-data-set-by-sampling-interpolation-to-improve-chart-p

Comment: Maybe the alternative is use dygraph, as said before. I did a test using the [beachmark test](http://dygraphs.com/tests/dygraph-many-points-benchmark.html) with 43200 points and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a reply to a very old question, but I stumbled across it and I thought an answer might help someone else having a similar requirement!

You can have a look at [LightningChart JS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js/). It's a lightweight and fast charting library built on WebGL and Canvas. We have a few [interactive examples](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/) that also showcase [fast load times (static)](https://arction.github.io/lcjs-showcase-renderingSpeed/) as well as [scrolling (dynamic)](https://arction.github.io/lcjs-showcase-streamingData/) point data as well.

Full disclosure: I am a developer for LightningChart, however, I think you may find this very useful.