# Fastest JS Library / web library for graphs

Tags: javascript, performance, visualization

I'm basically asking the same question as this guy, but newer: [Fastest javascript charting library for really huge data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665744/fastest-javascript-charting-library-for-really-huge-data)

All the libraries seem to say their the "fastest".
I'm doing this so I can make a mobile application that can show several hundred line charts at the same time, however the way I'm doing it now (With plot.ly express) is so slow sometimes it crashes the phone. They also should support some limited interactivity, like zooming and panning.

Cross posted to: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/84514/fastest-js-library-web-library-for-graphs

Comment: Hi, questions that seek recommendations about libraries, tools, etc. aren't very much welcome here on StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/

Comment: I'm not sure why Stranger wrote that. The link they provided has no commentary on questions that seek recommendations. If you dig into some of the links there, you do get to this post from 2010: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ which actually specifically talks about *how* to ask for product recommendations. So it would seem that StackOverflow has always been intended to be a platform which includes questions seeking recommendations, and the guidelines are more about how to ask in a helpful way.

Comment: Further, the commentary on that link about asking for product recommendations was this: "If you’re asking for a product recommendation of some kind, you want answers to contain detailed information about the features and how they can be used, and why you might want to choose one over the other." I believe your question satisfies that requirement, so it's unclear why it has been downvoted.

Comment: On further reading, Stranger intended to link here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

There is stated: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for SO as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

This is changed since the early days of StackOverflow; these Q's were common. I can understand the rationale, but it's quite a shame. They are very helpful when specific enough and the answer is obviously a particular tool.

Comment: My feelings about this are that the medicine is worse than the disease; meaning that too many helpful questions are lost by this policy, in the name of moderation convenience. Though of course I didn't live through whatever led to this policy shift.

Comment: I suppose a question which gets at what you're looking for and isn't explicitly seeking a library recommendation would be, "I am using JS to make very dense line charts. My current solution is crashing test phones. Here's an example I want to perform well on X hardware. How can I achieve that?"

Comment: I still think there ought to be room for being more explicit about what you're looking for. I came across this page through a DDG search for "fastest JS graph library". SO has the potential to be a very well curated repository of unbiased and well presented recommendations for things in this vein, so it's a shame that policy is preventing that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that LightningChart is the fastest available. You can see their [testing results](https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/performance/tester-results/) or try a [live test](https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/performance/tester/). They also have a huge variety of available charting methods.

Comment: Here’s a video of SciChart beating LightningChart in their own performance tests, while using around 1/2 of the memory https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3-r9cUFsAM

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) API (no library) if you want the fastest possible drawing (maybe in conjunction with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)).